# request.get url of second page of a search result

Tags: python, http, url, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to use request.get(url) to get the response of a url from a server.
The following code works for the url of the first page of a search result:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.epocacosmeticos.com.br/perfumes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

However, when I try to use the same code for the url of the second page of the the search result, which is "https://www.epocacosmeticos.com.br/perfumes#2",

```
r = requests.get("https://www.epocacosmeticos.com.br/perfumes#2")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

it returns the response of the first page. It ignores the '#2' at the end of the URL. How can I get the response of the second page of a search result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a web proxy like [BurpSuite](https://portswigger.net/burp) to view the requests made by the page. When you click on the "Page 2" button, this is what is being sent in the background:

```
GET /buscapagina?fq=C%3a%2f1000001%2f&PS=16&sl=f804bbc5-5fa8-4b8b-b93a-641c059b35b3&cc=4&sm=0&PageNumber=2 HTTP/1.1
```

Therefore, this is the url you will need to query if you want to properly scrape the website.
BurpSuite also allows you to play with the requests, so you can try changing the request (like changing the 2 for a 3) and see if you get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this website uses dynamic html. Because of this, the second results page is not a "new page", but the same page with the search content reloaded.

You probably won't be able to scrap only using requests. This probably requires a browser. [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Headless-Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) are good choices for this job, and after that you can use beautifulSoup to parse.